# How to use regex in zopim condition

Tags: regex

Currently I am using zopim as third party for chat application for my site. I have given one condition for a particular URL and it is working well for that URL.

My problem is I want to add new URL by using regex but I am not able to add it, please help me with it. I have tried to use two methods

```
(index)
```

OR

```
#<MatchData "http://localhost:5005/index2.html" | MatchData http://localhost:5005/index3.html" >
```